# Debugging between two different processes using 'Visual Studio for Code'

Tags: angular, debugging

I have a Angular project. I have another project where I have created a web server using 'Node JS'.

My Angular code calls API to Node server project. I need to set debugging so that I can jump from Angular to 'Node JS' project.

Any pointers would be helpful.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't work? Are you able to debug anything?

Comment: Are these two projects opened in two different windows of VSCode? Or is your angular project a subfolder of the node server and you wish to debug server/client together?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is Compound launch configurations.

From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations

An alternative way to start multiple debug session is by using a so-called compound launch configuration. A compound launch configuration lists the names of two or more launch configurations that should be launched in parallel. Compound launch configurations show up in the launch configuration drop down menu.

Example launch.json that starts multiple node applications:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Server",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Client",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/client.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Server", "Client"]
        }
    ]
}
```

For general information on Launch Configurations: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: Thanks for the update and link. I will try this and check.

Comment: If you run into any issues, post your launch.json and we can debug from there.